# How to achieve pagination and totaling through tablesorter?

Tags: tablesorter

I was trying to achieve total using tablesorter for every 10 records shown through tablesorter's pagination.

Comment: what you have tried so far? add codes that you tried

Comment: Totaling of what? Number of pages, rows, or certain column values? Please elaborate and share code.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I have suppose 50 records for a table and when I use Pagination from tablesorter plugin setting size= 10, it's gets distributed to 5 pages. And when I use the math widget to calculate sum of a particular column then It gives me the total of the 50 records for that column. So if I want to display sum of 10 records per page, how can I achieve that.